# Java : How to create an array from object then store String and double in that array

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, object

I want to create an array from object then store in that array with 2 different type of date 
i'm still learning java and this is kinda my  task and i searched many times and have find nothing  so please i need your help :D 
the base class :

```
package com.matcho.task;

public class Subject {
    String name;
    Double grade;

    public Subject(String myname, double myGrade) {
        name = myname;
        grade = myGrade;
    }

    public void printermethod() {
        System.out.println("Your Subject is " + name + " and ur grade is "
                + grade);
    }
}
```

and this is the main class :

```
package com.matcho.task;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class subjectUseing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String studentName = "";
        double studentGrade = 0;
        Subject object1 = new Subject(studentName, studentGrade);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please, Enter the Size of the Array : ");
        int arraySize = input.nextInt();
        Subject[] gradeArray = new Subject[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < gradeArray.length; i += 2) {
            if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Please, Enter Subject Number Grade");
                studentGrade = input.nextDouble();
                studentGrade = object1.grade;
                gradeArray[i] = object1.grade; 
                //Error said (cannot convert  from Double to Subject)
                //object1.grade = (Double)gradeArray[i];
                //gradeArray[i] = object1.grade;
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please, Enter Subject Number Name");
                studentName = input.next();
                studentName = object1.name;
                //Error said (cannot convert  from String to Subject)
                gradeArray[i] = new Subject(object1.name, object1.grade);
                // gradeArray[i] = object1.name;
                // gradeArray[i] = new String(object1.name); // Failed T_T
            }

        }// For End
        for (int i = 0; i < gradeArray.length; i += 2) {
            System.out.println("Your Grade in each Subject is : "
                    + gradeArray[i] + " " + gradeArray[i + 1]);
        }// For End
    }
}
```

i tried many ways and search many times but found nothing so please i need help because  this error
[cannot convert  from Double to Subject] blow up my mind :D

Comment: So, you're trying to store a `Double` in a `Subject` array and you don't know why this doesn't work? It is basically like a "shape toy". The rectangle doesn't fit in the triangle hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### By Definition

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type

You can not create an array then fill it with values of other types.
In your code you've created an array of Subject then all it's elements should be of type Subject , The members of Subject class doesn't matter at this point the array should handle Elements of type Subject.
In your logic "Business requirements " you're asked to create an array which holds the values of Student subject plus their Grades , then you say OK Easy task and you create the array and then you try to store grades and names of an object of Subject Class in the array Saying that
" Object is a reference type , and so as it's members " but NO!! it's not;
Your array should contains only Subject Elements
Take a look in the correct solution:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter array size");
    int size = in.nextInt();
    Subject[] subjects = new Subject[size];
    String name;
    Double grade;
    Subject object;
    for(int i =0; i<size; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Subject name: ");
        name=in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Subject Grade: ");
        grade = in.nextDouble();
        object = new Subject(name,grade);
        subjects[i] = object;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        System.out.println("Subject name is "+subjects[i].name + " Grade is "+subjects[i].grade);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You basically need to simplify your loop: on each iteration of the loop, ask for both the subject name and the grade, then create one object to store them both:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gradeArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the subject name");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the subject grade");
    double grade = input.nextDouble();
    gradeArray[i] = new Subject(name, grade);
}
```

Note the declaration of the variables inside the loop - you don't need them outside the loop, so don't declare them there.

Then for display, you'd just use:

```
for (Subject grade : gradeArray) {
  System.out.println(grade);
}
```

Again, there's no need to skip every other item in the array - each element in the array is a reference to a `Subject` object, which contains both a name and a grade.

(Or add `getName` and `getGrade` methods to `Subject` so that you can customize the output.)

Note that you may find `Scanner` a bit of a pain to work with - `nextDouble()` won't consume a line break, for example, which may mean you get an empty string when reading the next name. You might want to consider just reading a line at a time and using `Double.parseDouble` to parse a string. (Or use `NumberFormat`.)

Answer (score 0):

You created an array of Subject objects, but you are storing Double.

```
studentGrade = object1.grade;
gradeArray[i] = object1.grade;
```

You should store it like:

```
object1.grade = studentGrade;
gradeArray[i].grade = object1.grade;
```

But as already mentioned, you don't need so many local variables. You could dou it lik:

```
gradeArray[i].grade = input.nextDouble();
```